# Does node created within a sub-function stay valid even after the function exited?

Tags: javascript, onsubmit

I have project for my php class where I have to enter First name, last name, email, and phone number and output returns the exact values. (but I will only put the 'first name' code for editing).

I have a function in  of html that gets called from 'onsubmit' inside

```
<script>
function validate3(){
alert ("1validate3 called");
var elemFnameSpan = document.createElement("span");
var elemFnameBr = document.getElementById("idFnameBr");
var elemFnameBrParent = elemFnameBr.parentNode;

elemFnameBrParent.insertBefore(elemFnameSpan,elemFnameBr);
elemFnameSpan.id = "idFnameErr";
elemFnameSpan.style.color="red";
elemFnameSpan.innerHTML="";

var elemFname=document.getElementById("idFname");
var elemFnameValue = elemFname.value;

var errorFlag=false;

if (elemFnameValue == null || elemFnameValue ==""){
    elemFnameSpan.innerHTML ="required field";
        return false;
}
else{
    elemFnameSpan.innerHTML="";
}
if(errorFlag==true){
    return false;
}
return true;
}
</script>


<form onsubmit="return validate3()" action = "ContactInfo.php">
First Name<span style="color:red">*</span>
<input type="text" name = "Fname" size = "10" id="idFname" onchange="eraseFnameErr()"/>
<br id="idFnameBr" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
```

The function creates a node 'elemFnameSpan' before 
 of id 'idFnameBr'. If the textinput for first name is empty, elemFnameSpan.innerHTML outputs "required field", and false on 'onsubmit' . My problem is that the output doesn't refresh everytime the submit button is called, so 'required field' outputs get extended next to each other.

I am having difficulty resolving this situation and tried to remove the previous child node everytime the new function is called, but that didn't work either for me yet.

Comment: I tried declaring elemFnameSpan, elemFnameBr, and elemFnameBrParent outside the function (so that they are global) so that 'elemFnameSpan.innerHTML' would only be changed as the 'onsubmit' is re-used.

Comment: i dont see node.js, node.js is a backend server that uses V8 javascript engine, much like php is a backend server language. It has nothing to do with html nodes. Tag removed

Comment: sorry, but thanks for explaining. We are just learning about node for my php and HTML class, and I have been having so much confusion.  I don't understand why the output message doesn't refresh, and instead get extended next toeach other. \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you append any DOM node, it never removed unless you do it explicitly.
I can suggest two ways to achieve your goal.

First, you can save the node in a global variable.

```
var elemFnameSpan;
function validate3(){
    alert ("1validate3 called");
    if (!elemFnameSpan) {
        elemFnameSpan = document.createElement("span");
    }

    var elemFnameBr = document.getElementById("idFnameBr");
    var elemFnameBrParent = elemFnameBr.parentNode;
```

Or, set id to `elemFnameSpan` and find it every time the form is submitted.

```
function validate3(){
    alert ("1validate3 called");
    var elemFnameSpan = document.getElementById('whatever_you_want');
    if (!elemFnameSpan) {
        elemFnameSpan = document.createElement("span");
        elemFnameSpan.setAttribute('id', 'whatever_you_want');
    }

    var elemFnameBr = document.getElementById("idFnameBr");
    var elemFnameBrParent = elemFnameBr.parentNode;
```

Comment: thanks Mr. taggon. Your first sentence was really helpful to ease my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you have already created the span element, if you have grab it by using `getElementById`, if you havent then create it.

```
//This is an "if" shortcut, if getElementById returns null
//the code in right side will execute and the return value
//will be put in eleFnameSpan
var eleFnameSpan = document.getElementById("idFnameErr") || document.createElement("span");
var elemFnameBr = document.getElementById("idFnameBr");

//Check parentNode on elemFnameBr if it is null/undefined then it hasnt
//been added to the dom yet
if(!elemFnameBr.parentNode){
    //No need to store the parentNode (unless needing it else were in code)
    elemFnameBr.parentNode.insertBefore(elemFnameSpan,elemFnameBr);
    elemFnameSpan.id = "idFnameErr";
    elemFnameSpan.style.color="red";
    elemFnameSpan.innerHTML="";
}
```

The rest of the code can stay the same

What is happening is you are just creating a new span on each click, and since on each click you add a new span and edit that one instead of the original one you keep getting new message stacked next to each other.